# Hudson Continuous Integration

Tags: java, hudson

I am just new to hudson ci. and want to know is there any way to configure it to fetch the source java code from local drive such c:... , d:...

Right now, i dont have any source code repository.

If there is a way, please let me know. thanks

Comment: If you want to use version control but without needing a central repository you could try `git`. You could even use github as a central repository which would be an automatic backup of your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Execute Shell function for the build. Have the following commands (if using Linux):

```
rm -rf /path/to/hudson/workspace
cp -r /path/to/source /path/to/hudson/workspace
# Do the rest of your build actions here
```

EDIT: That said, have a look at the other answers. There's no point having a CI without an SCM system. If you're just playing around with Hudson to see how it looks/feels then you can do what I suggested, but **please** don't make it a permanent solution.

Comment: For a temporary solution I'd still use the File System SCM that jeha suggested.

Comment: I agree the File System SCM is a much better system if you are going to spend any more than 10 minutes playing around with it. I will change the wording of my answer to use 'could' instead of 'should' =)

Comment: @Sarathi To be honest, jeha's answer is more applicable than mine.

Answer (score 6):

My advice: create a source code repository, even if it's just on your local drive.

You **must** have a source code repository if you want to do *any* serious software development.

And doing continuous integration without a source code repository is backwards anyway: What do you *do* when your CI tells you that you have a regression? You can no longer look at the old source code, so the use of that information is very limited.

Comment: +1: CI will detect you need to run another build when you check in some changes.  If you don't have source control you would have to tell it when you build, which you could do yourself in your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [File System SCM](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/File+System+SCM) (Plugin ID: `filesystem_scm`) for that purpose.

> Simulate File System as SCM by checking file system last modified date, checkout(), pollChanges(), ChangeLog and distributed build are all supported.

But having a real SCM is crucial for serious development.